# Computing a label from a label and relative offset

Tags: bazel

I have a macro that is generating two rules to avoid circularity issues. For a call like `yaspl_bootstrap_library(name=foo, deps=[":bar"])` I want to generate the following rules:

`yaspl_library(name=foo, deps=[":bar"])
yaspl_srcs(name=foo_srcs, deps=[":bar_srcs"])`

Thus I need a function to turn `":bar"` into `":bar_srcs"`. And while the obvious string concatenation works in this example it fails in the case where `"//lib/foo"` needs to be turned into `"//lib/foo:foo_srcs"`.

This seems like a common thing that would happen in macros yet I cannot seem to find anything that does it easily.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll point out that this kind of string manipulation will not work with the `select` function (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select).

If it's not an issue for you, you can go ahead. This function can be written in a .bzl file. I agree this label manipulation functions should become available. In the meantime, you can try this function:

```
def explicit_label(label):
  if ":" in label or "//" not in label:
    return label
  return label + ":" + label[label.rfind("/")+1:]


explicit_label(dep) + "_srcs"
```